# 2013: Crawler failing execution of proc_MSS_GetNextCrawlBatch due to datediff overflow

Tags: 2013, search, crawling

**Up front disclosure:** I am not a SharePoint admin. We don't have a SharePoint admin. I just try to solve problems.

I was hearing reports of connection problems with one of our UAT SQL instances.

Querying connection metadata for the instance, I found that it had ~1000 connections against the SharePoint 2013 crawl store database. Almost all executing (or last tried to execute) the stored procedure `dbo.proc_MSS_GetNextCrawlBatch`.

Since I have the necessary permissions to be able to connect to the SharePoint server, I spelunked through central admin until I found what seemed like a relevant error page. With more spelunking and some googling I found the location of the SharePoint log file, where I see the following error repeated many times:

> ManagedSqlSession caught a SqlException executing the following command: 'proc_MSS_GetNextCrawlBatch'. Connection string was: '[redacted]'  Original exception message: 'The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.'

OK good, familiar territory.

Pulling apart the guts of the stored procedure and using parameters I found from a SQL trace, I have determined that one of the query columns is defined as `datediff(millisecond, CrawlQueue.TimeInsertedInQueue, getutcdate())`, and that there are rows in the `MSSCrawlQueue` table with a TimeInsertedInQueue value back in 2017. Clearly the number of milliseconds between a date in 2017 and today's date is going to overflow.

So, I have the problem diagnosed down to this very specific issue. What I don't know is: how do I fix it? Or rather, what is the *correct* way to fix it?

I mean, I could simply delete all the rows from the `MSSCrawlQueue` table, but I expect there is a right way to solve this problem which is more subtle than taking off and nuking it from orbit.